# Calling JavaScript sibling function inside parent function

Tags: javascript

I’m struggling with this and I haven’t found anything conclusive about this.

How can I call the function `y()` inside the function `z()` without altering the code's structure?

I tried using this but it didn’t work.

```js
function x(){

    function y(){
    console.log("sal y")
  }
  
  function z(){
    console.log("sal z");
    y()
  }
 
}
```

Comment: This is working. What is the issue? 
You just need to call `x()` somewhere and call `z()` somewhere inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code inside `z` calls `y` in the correct way – that’s not the problem. The reason you’re not seeing output in your snippet is that you’re never calling function `z`. If I edit function `x` to call `z`, and I edit the top level to call function `x`, it works.

```js
function x() {
  function y() {
    console.log("sal y");
  }

  function z() {
    console.log("sal z");
    y();
  }
  
  z(); // added
}

x(); // added
```